# Django OneToOneField looses relation by returning None after save()

Tags: django, database, orm

I'm a bit confused by a Django behavior and I couldn't find this in any related questions or the official documentation.

For example, in the code below:

```py
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.OneToOneField(Category)

post = Post(title='My Title')
post.category = Category(name='My Category')
post.category.save()
# Here: post.category => Category(pk=1, name="My Category") 
# Great the category has been saved and has a primary key, and is on the `post` instance (that still needs to be saved)
post.save()
# Here: post.category => None 
# Why did the saving of post loose the category that was created and linked to the post ?
```

I create a Post object. I then create a category on it that I save prior to saving the post. But when I call the `post.save()` method, the `post.category` is cleared and set to None. Why is that ?

I've fixed it by doing the following which introduces an additional `category` variable:

```py
post = Post(title='My Title')
category = Category(name='My Category')
category.save()
post.category = category
# Here: post.category => Category(pk=1, name="My Category") 
post.save()
# Here: post.category => Category(pk=1, name="My Category")
```

Why does introducing an additional variable change the behavior of the `save()` method ? When checking `post.category` before calling `post.save()`, the value of `post.category` is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

As django use [lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects) for it's queryset, the database transaction doesn't get execute until the save() are called:

```
post = Post(title='My Title')
# cool you created a post instance of Post model(not database record)
post.category = Category(name='My Category')
# you set the instance attribute value to an instance of Category model
post.category.save()
# calling save() execute database transaction -> it create category object in DB -> your post instance with its attribute never get saved

post.save()
# now you only be saving Post(title='My Title')
```

I don't think this is the best answer but it explained the flow

TLDR: your first save() only execute on the Category instance, not the Post instance

from the comment discussion:

in the docs docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/… it mentioned this `This example updates the blog attribute of an Entry instance entry, assuming appropriate instances of Entry and Blog are already saved to the database (so we can retrieve them below)` so yeah when you set something you should use the value retrieve from the database. There not much explaining to why we should do that, unless you want to dive into django model codes and see how it handle saving object

Comment: I know that the first `post.category.save()` only saves the category, that was expected 

Comment: @achedeuzot you actually never set the `post.category` to a category object, you only set it to an instance (which not exists in DB yet)

Comment: So for the relation to be properly persisted to the database, when setting the `category` field, the `Category` object **absolutely** needs to be an instance with a DB primary key ?

Comment: What's strange is that when inspecting `post.category` value before calling `post.save()`, the `post.category` instance *does* have a primary key set as it's been saved already.

Comment: in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields it mentioned this `This example updates the blog attribute of an Entry instance entry, assuming appropriate instances of Entry and Blog are already saved to the database (so we can retrieve them below):` so yeah when you set something you should use the value retrieve from the database. There not much explaining to why we should do that, unless you want to dive into django model codes and see how it handle saving object

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation, this last part is the most interesting one. The most confusing part to me is that Django won't complain or throw any error but silently fail in this case. Thanks for clarifying this. I'd be happy to accept your answer if you can duplicate your last comment in your answer because the crux of the answer is there, to make it more visible.

Comment: i don't think this should be accepted as an answer as i still haven't able to resolve on why django behave like that, i only referred thing on how it should be done from the docs :)